# sort.col command in Splus to R

Tags: r, matrix, s-plus

I have a code in Splus, but have to convert it into R, which is not a big thing. However I am very new to both softwares. This is the code I am struggling with:

```
bestmodind <- cbind(c(1:length(postprob)),postprob)
bestmodind <-sort.col(bestmodind,c(1,2), columns.to.sort.by=2,ascending=F)
```

The first command works fine, but the sort.col isn't an R command.

R does not recognize this command. What is sort.col doing, and how can I do the same thing in R? How do I modify this command?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
R > X <- data.frame(ind = 1:10, value = rnorm(10))
R > X
   ind        value
1    1  0.420723392
2    2  0.006186534
3    3  0.254721788
4    4 -0.473717372
5    5  1.155836603
6    6 -0.371284268
7    7 -1.095507310
8    8 -0.320578779
9    9 -1.201680230
10  10  1.771133865

R > library(dplyr)

R > arrange(X, desc(value))
   ind        value
1   10  1.771133865
2    5  1.155836603
3    1  0.420723392
4    3  0.254721788
5    2  0.006186534
6    8 -0.320578779
7    6 -0.371284268
8    4 -0.473717372
9    7 -1.095507310
10   9 -1.201680230
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't know the column names?

Comment: `X[order(desc(X[,2])), ]`

Comment: Tried this - R says it could not find the function desc. Is there a package I need to load?

Comment: `X[order(X[,2], decreasing = TRUE), ]` : this does not use `desc` function